# Least harmful way to disable APN temporarily?

Tags: settings, apn

I installed Quick Settings and turn off my mobile internet with this app. I have a motorola milestone with 2.1

However, that causes some trouble sometimes. When disabling it I lose more often my wifi connection. Android seems to try switching to APN when going to sleep. Turning on APN also does take a lot of time occasionally. Worst thing happened to me a few months ago: I had my APN turned off through Quick Settings. This app got an update and all of a sudden I couldn't connect to the internet over APN anymore. I had to do a full reset of my Android because of that.

Can you suggest a way to turn off APN in a less harmful way? (I still wonder why Android doesn't include that.)

Answer (score 1):

I really like APNdroid and haven't had problems with it at all. However, I've got an HTC Dream that's unlocked and running on AT&T so it is pretty much guaranteed that I'm not getting OTA updates.

You can always access your APN settings directly, so even if an update broke your APN settings, you should have been able to go in through `Settings >  Wireless controls > Mobile networks > Access point names` -- I have the option of manually adding one or more APNs and a "reset to defaults" button that will restore the T-Mobile APNs my phone shipped with.

Comment: I'll second APNDroid plus the widget. However, this week the author enabled the free version to allow Airpush notifications. This landed him in hot water with his users and Google. He's removed the library and apologized and will have a new version up soon. Otherwise, a highly useful app that I've employed a lot for testing and personal use.

Answer (score 0):

EDIT: Rereading your question suggested I'm pointing to the wrong direction altogether.

Try [OneClick widget](http://www.appbrain.com/app/oneclick-widget/fr.wewe.android.oneClickWidget).

[image: OneClick widget]

It opens the settings where you have to un-check Data Traffic (so, it's two click actually). This is the safe way to do it.

Quick Settings, like [APNdroid](http://www.appbrain.com/app/apndroid/com.google.code.apndroid), simply renames the APN thereby disabling/enabling it in one click. So, when you uninstall/update the app when the APN is renamed to something illegal, you will need to re configure your settings renaming the APN to the network provider's default.

Turning on the Data Traffic takes time because of the handshaking required as a 2G/3G standard, so this cannot be avoided.

Note: My phone(xperia x10 mini) comes with several widgets: Data Traffic, Power Control, Status switch (same thing!). So you might as well play with your phone's stock apps before venturing outside.

Comment: alright, i'll give that widget a try. I later noticed that APNdroid just adds a minus prior the internet server name. Don't know what happened at the time I had to reset my phone. Cant rrecover... Unfortunatly motorola doesnt provide a stock widget ;(

Comment: Tried the OneClick widget. It's the safest way to change setting. Unfortunatly there is no APN disable setting in my Milestone. So, there's no OneClick Widget to do that also ;(